# Upload image to Cloudinary using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cloud, image-uploading, cloudinary

Can someone help me how to upload an image into Cloudninary using CodeIgniter? I don't know how to install the Cloudinary to CodeIgniter and use it because I'm new to PHP CodeIgniter. Please help me thank you.

Update! I was able to solve it. See the first answer. cheers

Comment: SOers are not here to code for you. You ought to do more research and attempts before posting questions and asking for help up here. When you ask questions, be clear with where you get stuck. Post your codes and stack trace etc.

Comment: Fortunately I was able to install it to codeigniter successfully by my self, and a able to use.  I will post my solution step by step later when I got home. Thankyou for your comment. Sad for the down votes.

Answer (score 1):

1. First You need to download the cloudinary php script here https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php.
2. Now extract the downloaded file and copy the files from src folder.
3. Now in you codeigniter app, go to appplication folder and then third_party folder. Inside the third_party folder create a folder name cloudinary, and inside cloudinary folder paste the files from src folder that you extracted lately.

**To use the cloudinary library:**

4. Now inside your controller, in a function. You need to set up first the api credentials like this:

   ```
   require APPPATH .'third_party/cloudinary/Cloudinary.php';
   require APPPATH .'third_party/cloudinary/Uploader.php';
   require APPPATH .'third_party/cloudinary/Api.php';
   ```

   Cloudinary::config(array( 
     "cloud_name" => "yourcloudname", 
     "api_key" => "yourapikey", 
     "api_secret" => "yoursecretkey" 
   ));
5. Now to upload:

   $data['upload'] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("image url you want to download");
6. And your done. for more information about the api you can then refer to the official documentation in http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
Cloudinary::config(array(
    "cloud_name" => "cloud_name",
    "api_key" => "*****",
    "api_secret" => "*****"
));

$image = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');

$cloudinaryImage = Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($image->tempName);

$entity->setFile($cloudinaryImage->url);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.