# Service not available when try to upload local files cloudinary + codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cloudinary

I have a problem when using cloudinary in codeigniter. At first, i integrate the library by following answers from

[Upload image to Cloudinary using PHP Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722599/upload-image-to-cloudinary-using-php-codeigniter)

It worked when i uploaded online image. But failed when i tried to upload local image. The error is

```
Error in loading http://localhost/admin-simple/assets/img/avatar1_small.jpg - 503 Service Unavailable
```

Here is my code :

```
Cloudinary::config(array( "cloud_name" => "my_cloud_name", "api_key" => "1234", "api_secret" => "ABCD" ));


$data['upload'] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("http://localhost/admin-simple/assets/img/avatar1_small.jpg");


$this->load->view('partials/sukses_upload_gambar',$data);
```

Can anyone help me ? Because i've been stuck for hours. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code here so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @chad i have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Cloudinary documentation, when uploading a file from your computer, you should specify the filepath instead of the URL of your local server:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("/home/my_image.jpg")
```

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration